# optgroup lable and select options group not to repeat

Tags: php, html, sql

Grouping items by their category works but its not placing all the products of the category in one *optgroup* but repeating it.

All the items should be in one group not separate as an duplicate group.

[image: Select options example]

```
<select style="width: 25%;" name="item[]" id="item1" class="item browser-default custom-select-new"> 
    <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>
<?php
$conn_register = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
$Comid = "27";

$levy_input = "";
$records = mysqli_query($conn_register, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$Comid'");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
    $price = $data['new_total_rate'];
    $product = $data['product'];

    $sqlii = "SELECT DISTINCT category 
                FROM addproducts 
                WHERE `name` LIKE '$product' 
                ORDER BY 'category' ";
    $resultii = $conn_register-> query($sqlii);
    $prof= $resultii -> fetch_assoc();
    $Pcategory = $prof["category"];

    echo '<optgroup label="'. $Pcategory .'">';
                            
    echo '<option value="' . $data['product'] . '"  
            data-new_price_rate="' . $data['new_total_rate'] . '" 
            data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" 
            data-tax="' . $data['tax'] . '"
            data-PriceRate_NoDiscount="' . $data['new_price_rate'] . '">'
        . $data['product'] . '</option>
    </optgroup>';     
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](/q/321299/90527) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Comment: @outis The end result will be the same but i made the changes.

Comment: The `$sqlii` statement makes it look like a product could be in multiple categories, but the output only uses a single category for each product (which seems the correct approach). What is the relationship between customer products and categories? How should this be handled for output? Moreover, the use of `LIKE` when comparing `addproducts.name`  suggests `customer_product.product` holds a pattern rather than, say, a product name. Is `customer_product.product` supposed to be a name or a pattern? If the former, why is `LIKE` used?

Comment: A product is only in one category at a time but multiple products in a single category, i use "LIKE" instead of "=" to select where the product is in witch category. Products and categories has an relationship. My problem is the query "while loop" retrieves the information as it is in the database,table.

Comment: You have written code that creates the opening `optgroup` tag, then creates _one_ `option` inside it, and then closes the `optgroup` again. There isn't a loop _inside_ the optgroup, there are no _conditions_ on the output of the `optgroup` tags ... so how could this _possibly_ work to get the result you want then?

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code or error messages. This is an edge case, but it would be better to show the generated HTML, instead of how a browser renders that HTML.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. For yet another, code in comments is often unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you unconditionally output an `<optgroup>` with each iteration; thus, if you don't want to output each time through, you'll need to (at the very least) make the output conditional. In many circumstances this wouldn't be sufficient, as sequential rows may be in different groups; instead, you'd need to group the results in PHP, and then iterate over the results. Here, with a few alterations an `ORDER BY` clause will ensure the items in each category are processed sequentially. The current statements aren't sufficient, as the categories are retrieved in a separate statement, which not only prevents the `ORDER BY` from making items in a category contiguous but is inefficient, as it makes many more requests than necessary.

The two statements can be combined with a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT cp.product AS name,
       cp.description,
       cp.tax,
       cp.new_price_rate,
       cp.new_total_rate,
       ap.category
  FROM customer_product AS cp
    LEFT JOIN addproducts AS ap ON cp.product = ap.name
  WHERE customer LIKE ? -- NB: parameter for prepared statement
  ORDER BY ap.category
```

If there's a 1:N relationship between customer_product.product and ap.name, then the query will need to be modified so as to only return one row for each `customer_product` row (a simple approach is to group by all the `cp` rows).

To determine when to output an `<optgroup>`, the code will need to detect when the category changes. This is easily accomplished by storing the current category, and comparing it to the category for a new row.

Generally speaking, you must consider what happens on the first, intermediate and last iterations.

The first iteration is important in that you want to force the output of an optgroup. As long as the stored category will never equal a category from the DB, this is essentially automatic.

Additionally, no `</optgroup>` close tag should be output on the first iteration. A simple way to skip this the first time through is to use a variable to hold the tag to output, which is initialized to just the open tag, and then add the close tag the first time an `<optgroup>` is output. Another is to have a flag recording whether there's an optgroup to close (initialized to `FALSE` and set to `TRUE` when `<optgroup>` is output), and outputting the close tag only if the flag is true.

After the last iteration, the last `<optgroup>` must be closed. Under the assumption that there's at least 1 product in 1 category, you should be able to unconditionally output a close tag after the loop.

Note that the sample code in the question mixes many different kinds of tasks, primarily DB access and output. This violates [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Instead, each should be placed in separate modules. The exact methodology to achieve this is well beyond the scope of this Q&A, but a simplified method is used in the sample code below.

Be sure to encode any non-HTML strings using [`htmlspecialchars`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars), both to prevent injection and broken HTML.

```
<?php
// initially, there's no category
$category = NULL;
// the category tag; will be updated to close the previous element the first time it's output
$catTag = '<optgroup ';
// attributes for each <option> element
$attrs = [
    'value' => 'name',
    'data-new_price_rate' => 'new_total_rate',
    'data-description' => 'description',
    'data-tax' => 'tax',
    'data-PriceRate_NoDiscount' => 'new_price_rate',
];
?>
<select>
  <option disabled>Click to see products</option><!-- Note: this smells a bit. -->
  <?php
    // note there's no sign of DB access; the products could come from anywhere
    foreach ($customerProducts->fetch($comid) as $product) {
        // The core of the answer: output a new optgroup only then when the category changes
        if ($category != $product['category']) {
            echo $catTag, 'label="', htmlspecialchars($product['category']), "\">\n";
            // from now on, close the previous element when there's a new optgroup
            $catTag = "</optgroup>\n<optgroup ";
        }
        // output the current product as an option element
        ?>
        <option<?php foreach ($attrs as $attr => $prop) {
                    echo ' ', $attr, '="', htmlspecialchars($product[$prop]), '"';
                } ?>><?= htmlspecialchars($product['name']) ?></option>
        <?php
        $category = $product['category'];
    }
  ?>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

The sample assumes that every product is in 1 category, so `$product['category']` isn't null. However, if any product isn't in a category, it should still work unless every product in the results is in no category, in which case there will be no `<optgroup>`s and the final `</optgroup>` won't close anything, producing invalid HTML.

The following (untested) sample is only for the purposes of separating DB access from the HTML generation. Search elsewhere for information on topics such as [DALs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer), [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and the [Traversable](https://php.net/Traversable) interface (which is supported by [`mysqli_result`](https://php.net/mysqli_result), though [PDO](https://php.net/PDO) has better support, including allowing you to set the result type to something other than an associative array with [`PDOStatement->setAttribute`](https://php.net/PDOStatement.setAttribute)).

```
class CustomerProducts {
    static $statements = [
        'read' => 'SELECT […]',
    ];
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->read = $db->prepare(self::$statements[read]);
    }
    function fetch($id) {
        $this->read->bind_param('i', $id);
        if ($this->read->execute()) {
            return $this->read->get_result();
        } else {
            // handle failure with e.g. an exception
            throw …;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Such comprehensive answers should not be written on new pages, but (ideally) on the most attractive earlier question.  All basic questions asked in 2022 are duplicates.  The next chapter in Stack Overflow's evolution is to consolidate and refine its content.  We need to get all answers on a given topic in one pile so that researchers don't have to visit 10 different pages to determine if they've seen every angle.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, i joined the two query's with a left join and added a if statement to prevent repeating in the while loop.

```
 <?php
 $conn_register = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'register');
 $Comid = "28";

 $records = mysqli_query($conn_register, "SELECT customer_product_product AS name,
category,new_total_rate,quantity,customer_product_tax,customer_product_description
 FROM customer_product AS cp
 JOIN addproducts AS ap ON customer_product_product = ap.name
 WHERE customer_product_customer = '$Comid'
 ORDER BY category ");
 ?>

 <select>
 <option selected disabled>select product</option>
 <?php
 $New_test_cat = "";
 while ($qqa = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
 $test_cat = $qqa['category'];

 if ($test_cat !== $New_test_cat) {
 $New_test_cat = $test_cat;
 echo '<optgroup label="'.$New_test_cat.'">';
 }

 echo '<option value="'.$qqa['name'].'" >'.$qqa['name'].' </option>';
 
 }
 echo '</optgroup>';
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: This still suffers from similar issues: the `<optgroup>` is closed unconditionally with *every iteration*. It mixes DB access with output.